# Can I manipulate a window(process) that I have not created?

Tags: windows, vb.net, user-interface

I have this application that I haven't created and I don't have the source for. But it's really handy in handling and recording the time I've used on different projects. But it has this annoying pop-up that comes up that contains a window and some debug text I believe. It wasn't done by a professional, it was just a hobby project. Everything is working even though this window appear. So I was wondering if it's possible to "hijack" a window and minimizing or closing it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You could hide the window if you have its title. There are other ways to do it, but..

The following application does a few tweaks on another window, check it out:

[Window manipulation using window-handle from different process on MS Windows(XP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023942/window-manipulation-using-window-handle-from-different-process-on-ms-windowsxp/4048423#4048423)

Comment: @Kenny you can close it too! The link above also shows you how.