# OpenCv CvWindow removal

Tags: c#, .net, opencv

I am trying to get the output of a camera and display it in a c# gui using OpenCvSharp. This is the code I have based on samples. However, this code pops up a second window, CvWindow, which I would like to remove. Is this possible? Removing the CvWindow from my code makes the camera stream not appear.

```
CvCapture cap= CvCapture.FromCamera(0);
CvWindow win= new CvWindow("camera");

while (CvWindow.WaitKey(10) < 0)
{
    IplImage img= Capture.QueryFrame();
    Bitmap bmp= BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(img);
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}
win.Close();
```

Comment: Deleting the lines `CvWindow win= new CvWindow("camera");` and `win.Close();` doesn't work? An alternative is to use the win32 API to hide that window.

Comment: Deleting the lines does work in the sense that the second window disappears. But for some reason, when I do that, the program enters the while loop, the video is not displayed and everything locks up. I have not been able to figure out why and thus assumed that CvWindow was somehow necessary.Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: If that is true, that only happens with the C# wrapper. You can try to move the window out of the screen, or use the win32 API to hide it for real.

Comment: I've already tried removing it with the Win32API as well. For some reason, that doesn't work either. I can hide other windows, but not the CvWindow. Moving it off the screen is what I'm doing now, but it still shows up in the taskbar.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4056379/176769) has an interesting reference on how to hide windows based on its title, is that the trick you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I display OpenCvSharp video feeds in a Windows Form. http://www.prodigyproductionsllc.com/articles/programming/use-opencv-in-a-windows-form-application-in-c/.

The best way to hide the window is to not show it in the first place. So, remove the line where you construct a new CvWindow. Then, you need to move your while-loop into a new thread and make it continuous with something like "while(true)". If you do not run it on a separate thread, your app will freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out using the Win32 API to hide the window was the way to go. However, you have to make sure to hide parent window of the CvWindow.