# Want to resize other applications running in Windows

Tags: windows

I'm looking for the cleanest way to get all open windows and have access to moving/resizing them. I'd like to be able to get their current locations and move them where I'd like.

I want access to all windows, not just top level ones.

Thanks

Comment: You understand the most controls are windows themselves, right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your sentence. To clarify: I want my application to resize other windows (i.e, Chrome, Word, etc...)

Comment: What Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams meant was that you don't actually want to resize every single window on the system, because it would also resize dialogs, buttons, text boxes, toolbars, etc. What you really want is access to only top-level windows. Better yet, you want only top-level windows that do not have owners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- One way to get the list of processes running is shown on this tutorial: [Win32 APIs for Process Retrieval](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/Tasks.aspx). Another way is through [EnumDesktopWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- If at this point you have access to the window's handle then you can move it with [SetWindowPos()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28VS.85%29.aspx). But if you only have access to it's title, then you'll need to use [FindWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28VS.85%29.aspx) first and obtain a handle to that window.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023942/window-manipulation-using-window-handle-from-different-process-on-ms-windowsxp/4048423#4048423) that shows how to do several different operations on a specific window, including how to move it to another location.