# WPF App on Top of Desktop

Tags: c#, wpf

I need help in WPF. I am developing an application which will be fixed position on top of the desktop with a height of 100.

This is working fine as it is fixed on top and it is taking the full width of the current resolution.

What I need is that I want other applications to resize and leave the space for my app when it is opened.

Currently, when I open my app, the other application's top part is behind my Window.

Please help!!!

Comment: So you looking for a way for your program to automatically control resizing of all other applications that may open?

Comment: Basically, I want my application to be always on top part of the desktop and other applications should not take that space and resize their height accordingly

Comment: Check out this post - [Resize other applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767992/want-to-resize-other-applications-running-in-windows)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy. I shall check that, but please let me know if there is an inbuilt property of the window which can do this? There are many applications which do this!!

Comment: I do not want to resize all applications. I just want the currently active application to resize its height so that it comes below my application.